# python/django: pass class method to class variable

Tags: python, oop, django-models

so I'm working with `django-models` and I want to pass the quantity of objects that class have then pass it as model argument **LIKE SO**:

```py
class someclass:
    somevar = 'somevalue'
    
    def retrieve1():
        return somevar

    def retrieve2(self):
        return self.somevar

    def retrieve3():
        return someclass.somevar

    #returns NameError: name 'somevar' is not defined
    value1 = retrieve1()
    
    #returns TypeError: retrieve2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
    value2 = retrieve2()
    
    #returns NameError: name 'someclass' is not defined
    value3 = retrieve3()
```

I even tried to pass the `somevar` as instance with `__init__` but nothing good:

```py
class someclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.somevar = 'somevalue'
    
    #returns NameError: name 'self' is not defined
    value = self.somevar
```

what I'm missing here ????!
I tried every single thing like treat the method as `@classmethod`, `@staticmethod` nothing helped

here's the real code i'm struggiling with:

```py
class Box(models.Model):
    
   #so as u see, i'm trying to get the len of all objects that class holds
    def defaultOrder():
        return len(Box.objects.all()) + 1

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False, 
        unique=True,
       
       #here will be passed
        default= defaultOrder()
    )
    end_days = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    end_hours = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    end_minutes = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

sooo as u see, I just want to treat the class as I was outside of it !
It's realy hard to explain it in `CS` way, I hope you understand ..

Comment: What is order, why do you need it? Why is using the default  primary `id` field that is generated automatically not enough?

Comment: @Dunes I'm working on flashcards with [leitner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitner_system) system , so the box could be deleted,modified, order-changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is simply not possible. You are trying to use the class before it has been created. That is, you are invoking `defaultOrder()`, before the Box class has finished being created.

It looks like you are trying to implement an auto incrementing sequence, similar to a primary key. The primary key is usually exposed as `id`. But you can give the field another name if you like. eg:

```py
class Box(models.Model):
    order = models.fields.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Annoyingly, django only allows a model to have one `AutoField`, so you cannot create a separate `order` field to the default `id` field.
You might want to have a second `AutoField` if you wanted `order` to be changeable, so that you could reorder boxes if desired. It's doubly annoying, because implementing something like this directly in SQL is trivial. In PostgreSQL you might do something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE box(
    box_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, -- serial is an auto-incrementing 32-bit integer
    "order" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    content TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT box_order_unique UNIQUE ("order") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);

INSERT INTO box (content) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
SELECT * FROM box ORDER BY "order";
```

gives:

```
box_id  order   content
1       1       a
2       2       b
3       3       c
```

Then you could do something like:

```sql
BEGIN;
SET CONSTRAINTS box_order_unique DEFERRED;
UPDATE box SET "order" = 2 WHERE content = 'c';
UPDATE box SET "order" = 3 WHERE content = 'b';
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM box ORDER BY "order";
```

giving:

```
box_id  order   content
1       1       a
3       2       c
2       3       b
```

## Passing a callable in Django

`default` can be a callable. Which I think is actually the behaviour you want. Each time you insert a `Box` you want its value to be the current count of rows in the `Box` table, not just a static default. This would work, because the function would only ever be invoked after the class had been created.

```py
class Box(models.Model):
    def defaultOrder():
        # NB. count() requires less work by database than all(), and also less
        # data to be transferred from the
        return len(Box.objects.count()) + 1

    order = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False, 
        unique=True,
        # here will be passed -- NB. No brackets!
        default=defaultOrder
    )
```

This has the undesired side effect of causing an extra round trip to the database for each insert. Annoying again, because we know this is something the database can handle by itself.

Comment: the solution was in the last section of your answer <3, now about before it, the purpose that makes me doing this is because I'm working on the flash cards [leitner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitner_system) system, each box could be deleted and modified, now i think you understand why I would do that rather that `autoField`

Comment: and here's my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73244897/django-models-set-record-value-depends-on-the-existig-ones/73245075#73245075) that I post it after that one, it's simpler and more readable and the answer was just as you mentioned .

Comment: I've realised that one possible problem with your `defautOrder()` solution is that it assumes no rows are ever deleted from the table. For instance, if you insert two boxes and then delete the first then remaining row will have an order of 2. The next value that defaultOrder() will produce is 2 (number of rows (1) plus 1)! That will violate your uniqueness constraint and break any future inserts. Instead, you should use `Max()` instead. eg. `defaultOrder = lambda: Box.objects.aggregate(models.Max('order')) + 1`

Comment: actually I wrote a whole package for Logic handling and restrictions, but because after that problem I realized that I have a lot of work on my oop knowledge , thank you very much for your Note <3