# django-models set record value depends on the existig ones

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

yo, I have simple Question but it's answer sames to be not ,at all, maybe even not exist !

anyway, I just want to set a django-model field value based on existing ones, *LIKE*:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    #here is the struggle
    people = len(Person.objects.all())
     
    name = medels.Charfield()
    #pass it as argument
    peopleBeforeYou = models.CharField(default= people-1)
```

the idea is to set the `peopleBeforeYou` field default value to that same model QuerySet `len()`

any idea ????!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the function that counts the number of existing rows to a separate function outside of the class

```
def count_people():
    return Person.objects.count()


class Person(models.Model):
    peopleBeforeYou = models.IntegerField(default=count_people)
```

Comment: yup it works, it came to my mind several times but i was thinking that it will give me `ERROR: referenced before assignment`, so i didn't even try it hahaha I lost hours for my over thinking, anyway thank you so much <3